# SyntaxError: unterminated parenthetical for validating the local file path

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have to validate the local folder path which is in the following format : ..\sentinel\log .

I have old regular expression  ( /[\w]:\.*/))  for C:\sentinel\log and that was working. I need to make accept this path.

I have the following expresion from  [regexplibrary](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=file&c=-1&m=-1&ps=50&p=3)

> var pathRE = new RegExp("/^((../|[a-zA-Z0-9_/-\])*.[a-zA-Z0-9])"); Error :
>   SyntaxError: unterminated parenthetical

When i executing is throw this error

I am attaching the code that i have tried

```
function checkFolderpath(path) {
    try {
        //var pathRE = new RegExp(/[\w]:\\.*/);
        var pathRE = new RegExp("/^((\.\./|[a-zA-Z0-9_/\-\\])*\.[a-zA-Z0-9])");
        if (pathRE.test(path)) {
            $("#spanloggererror").html("");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            $("#spanloggererror").html(resx_Invalid_Loggerpath);
            valtemp = 1;
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err.Message);
    }
```

Please suggest me how to fix the issue.

Edit :

value of path : ..\Sentinel\log

Comment: what is the value of path

Comment: The `/` is an issue at the start

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regular expression should be constructed like this:

```
var pathRE = /^((..\/|[a-zA-Z0-9_/-\\])*.[a-zA-Z0-9])/;
```

The only time you really need to use the RegExp constructor is when you're building up a regular expression from separate pieces, dynamically.  You have to be careful with quoting forward-slash characters in the expression (`/`) when you use native regular expression syntax. You don't have to quote them inside `[ ]` groups, but you do need to double your backslashes.

That regular expression won't match `..\what\ever` because it only looks for forward slash at the start. It also won't match a terminal file name longer than two characters. I think a better one would be:

```
var pathRE = /^\.\.(?:\\[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)+/;
```

with appropriate changes for the file name characters you expect.

Comment: I have like this var pathRE = /^((..\/|[a-zA-Z0-9_/-\\])*.[a-zA-Z0-9])/; but its showing its "Syntax error in regular expression". One doubt Should i enclose within the double quotes or single quotes

Comment: @ThangamaniPalanisamy you don't need *any* quotes. You need to fix that first `[ ]` because that last `\` will mess it up.  Just use the regular expression in my answer.

Comment: I have your second expression it passing through with any error. But its not validating this path "..\Sentinel\log". Its says invalid path. Can you please correct regular expression to match the above specified string.

Comment: @ThangamaniPalanisamy hold on and I'll update the answer; it's a simple change.

Answer (score 3):

Escape the slash:

```
/^((\.\./|[a-zA-Z0-9_\/\-\\])*\.[a-zA-Z0-9])/
//          here   __^   and    add slash __^
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `/` inside `[ ]` groups.